# How to programmatically change current page on PrimeVue Paginator component?

Tags: vue.js, paginator, primevue

Can I set a current-page props on PrimeVue Paginator?

https://primefaces.org/primevue/paginator

I want to detect a query string to set current page

seems there is no props I can set?

I tried `:value`, `:current`, `:current-page`

no one is working, always on page 1.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `first` to retrieve and or modify the current position. If you have one row per page `:row="1"`, `first` equals `page - 1`.

```html
<Paginator
    v-model:first="first"
    :rows="1"
    :total-records="10"
    />
<Button @click="first = 0">Go to page 1</Button>
<Button @click="first = 2">Go to page 3</Button>
```

If you are displaying more than one row per page, e.g. `:row="10"` you have to some math ;-) Basically: `first = (page - 1) * rows`

```html
<Paginator
    v-model:first="first"
    :rows="10"
    :total-records="100"
    />
<Button @click="first = 0">Go to page 1</Button>
<Button @click="first = 20">Go to page 3</Button>
```

Comment: it works! I still don't understand the reason, but I will study further. thanks for replying and edit the question, some user.

Answer (score 1):

Just realized that you need to actually tell the `Paginator` how much you want to skip, not the math to calculate the `current page`.

```
<Paginator
    :rows="movieStore.movieLimitCount"
    @page="onPaginate"
    :totalRecords="movieStore.movieCount"
    class="mt-5"
    :alwaysShow="false"
    v-model:first="offset"
  />

<script setup>
const offset = ref(0);
const onPaginate = (e) => offset.value = e.rows * e.page;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by doing the following code, remembering that the page variable has an initial value of 1

```
<Paginator
        @page="onPage($event)"
        :rows="10"
        :pt="{
          root: (event) => {
            const itemForPage =  10;
            const currentPage =  this.page - 1;
            event.state.d_first = itemForPage * currentPage;
          },
        }"
        v-model:totalRecords="totalPage">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.

- Add v-model:first="offset"  to datatable tag.
- Make offset reactive by const offset = ref(0);
- Then put this code on the onMounted hook.

```
onMounted(() => {
    loadDataFromProp();
    const url = new URL(location.href);
    const page = url.searchParams.get('page');
    offset.value = (dt.value.rows * page ?? 1) - 1;
});
```